# Как передать список MultipartFile в контроллер?

Tags: java, spring

У меня есть такой контроллер (поменять его не могу):

```
@PostMapping
fun publish(@RequestPart files: List<MultipartFile>) {
    // doing something amazing
}
```

Не получается передать в него список файлов через `RestTemplate`. Пробовал простым `List<File>`, оборачивал файлы в `HttpEntity` c `Disposition` - не работает. Как это лучше сделать?

Comment: Для того, чтобы принять `MultipartFile`, `Content-Type` запроса должен быть `multipart/form-data`

Answer (score 0):

```
@PostMapping
fun publish(@RequestPart("files") MultipartFile[] files){}
```

Главное обратите внимание на то, чтобы каждое поле ввода файла должно иметь одно и то же имя `("files")`, чтобы к нему можно было обращаться как к массиву MultipartFile.